# Flutter prevent click through widget

Tags: flutter

How can I make a clickable widget with a ripple and a button inside?

Here is the code I have:

```
          Material(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("this column is clickable"),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ]
                )
              )
            ),
```

When clicking on the Column, everything works fine, the ripple effect go behind the IconButton as expected. But when clicking on the IconButton, the onPressed trigger is called but it also activates the InkWell. Is there a way to prevent in from activation the InkWell?

Comment: You want to the button that is inside the InkWell to not activate the InkWell animation when pressed, is this correct?

Comment: I've tried your code and the InkWell only gets activated if you long press. If it's just a tap only the IconButton animates.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14417

Comment: @JoãoSoares correct

Answer (score 0):

Put `Column` widget inside `GestureDetector` and set `excludeFromSemantics: true` like the following:

```
Material(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: GestureDetector(
        excludeFromSemantics: true,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("this column is clickable"),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ]
        ),
      )
    ),
  )
),
```

Its from this [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14417) post.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue, but the post looks helpful, thanks.

Comment: Strange because I tried it, it works! Can you share other info maybe we could help. What other parent widgets are you using?

Comment: here it is in dartpad: https://dartpad.dev/cca6f36ece4c3b2e241add4d62dc10c9

Comment: ya in the browser just hovering over the icon activates the whole thing and long press on the button in android emulator does the same too. A normal click though is fine.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately.  I had to create a bool that I can check/toggle to prevent the click from propagating.